# Desktop sharing application in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I want to make an application in Flex for desktop sharing. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to access desktop via Flex, you'll have to use some server app on the user machine to simulate mouse/keyboard events.
For example, you can use any VNC server (http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/index.html) with the Flex VNC client (http://www.wizhelp.com/flashlight-vnc/).

Answer (score -1):

Want to compete with Fog Creek CoPilot? ;-)

Well, I doubt that Flex running as SWF in a browser is able to do this due to sandbox limitations. Maybe, if you run Flex as AIR application, but I still doubt that AIR provides that level of access to the OS.

For Java there may be libraries that can do something like this using native interfaces.

Don't know how Copilot is doing this. I guess either using an Active X control or an native application that has to be installed.

After all I really doubt that you will be able to do this with Flex.